# installing OpenMediaVault 4 from usb stick fails with "failed to create file system"

Tags: usb, debian, bootable-media, ext4

I've been trying to install `OpenMediaVault 4.1.3` from an usb stick on my HP Microserver Gen8. I created the boot stick in various ways (`dd`, `etcher`, `UNetbootin`) but during installation (in the partitioning step) I repeatedly ended up with the following error message (and later "creating ext4 file system failed" appeared):

[image: error message during installation]

To create the stick with `dd`, I followed the official instructions [here](https://openmediavault.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/via_iso.html). I also made sure that SATA support is set to AHCI and I also tested versions 3.0.94 and 4.0.14.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue in the following way:

1. burn the openmediavault iso on a cd
2. format the usb stick with ext4 file system, under macOS I did this with:

   2.1 `brew install e2fsprogs`

   2.2 `sudo $(brew --prefix e2fsprogs)/sbin/mkfs.ext4 /dev/disk3`
3. plug in the ext4-formatted usb stick, boot from cd and follow the installation wizard 
   -> partitioning doesn't fail in this constellation for me